# Dispatch multiple actions using Redux Thunk and the await/async syntax to track loading

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am currently editing some reducers to be able to track the loading state of axios operations. Most of my async syntax is written in async/await fashion and would like to keep it that way to keep my code organized.

I am not sure how to dispatch two action creators one after the other: the first one to fire off the `FETCHING_USER` action type and keep track of the reduced `isFetching` state, while the other one to fire off the actual axios `GET` request. The code currently looks like this to get the API request:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/current_user`, {
    headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem("token") }
  });
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

I am not sure how to dispatch the `FETCHING_USER` and *then* fire off the `FETCH_USER` action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to modify your reducer to have `isFetching` statement and requesting and receiving data cases:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { isFetching: false, data: [] };

export default(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case REQUEST_USER: {
   return {...state, isFetching: true};
  }
  case RECEIVE_USER: {
   return {...state, isFetching: false, data: action.payload};
  }
  default: return state;
 }

}
```

Then modify your action to use try/catch statements:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
 dispatch({ type: REQUEST_USER });

 try {

  const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/current_user`, {
   headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem("token") }
  });
  
  dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_USER, payload: res.data });

 }
 catch(e){
   //dispatch your error actions types, (notifications, etc...)
 }
```

};

Then in component you can use condition like: isFetching ? //show loader : //show content (data[])